# Where do the ziplines go on each heist?

Tags: payday-3

Each heist lets you buy and place a zipline bag as one of the favor options. Where do these ziplines end up? Where should I consider placing a zipline instead of armor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No Rest for the Wicked**: Zipline goes from the roof of the bank to a roof in the alleyway. An interesting possibility for moving bags in relative quiet, but overall, probably not worth it vs just throwing bags across the parking lot.

**Road Rage**: Two ziplines go from the scaffold to the truck ramp, and from the scaffold to the middle of the bridge. Not that useful for securing loot, but an interesting way to take the scaffold as high ground. Probably better to just place an armor bag.

**Dirty Ice**: Zipline bag appears not to spawn at all. Picking the zipline on this heist is just a waste of $10,000.

**Rock the Cradle**: Zipline goes up the elevator shaft from the VIP area to the main floor. This one is very good in loud since it gives you a faster route to move bags from the vault to the main floor.

**Under the Surphaze**: Zipline goes from the fire escape to the dumpster by the harbor, near where the van is parked. Useful in stealth, since it gives you an alternate route in and out of the gallery.

**Gold & Sharke**: Zipline goes from the second floor of the lobby to the roof. A nice and quick way to secure loot vs taking it through the stairwell in loud.

**99 Boxes**: Zipline goes from the east side of the dockyard to the west side, precisely the same as the zipline that normally spawns on this heist. It's possible that placing a zipline bag puts the bag in an easier spot to get to, but overall this bag is not useful.

**Touch the Sky**: Zipline goes from the master bedroom to the loud escape on the balcony. This one is good in loud since it lets you secure the jewelry from the vault in the master bedroom via zipline rather than having to carry it through the penthouse.

**Turbid Station**: Zipline goes from the starting area to the top of the middle train, making for a decent alternate route into the railyard. Note: This zipline is placed at the beginning, and does not spawn a zipline bag.

**Cook Off**: Zipline goes from the street to the upstairs window of the house, making for a fast route back to the street.

**Syntax Error**: Zipline goes up the elevator near the stealth escape in stealth, or from the server rack to the control room in loud. Note: once the zipline is placed, it cannot be moved, so don't place the zipline in the elevator until you're ready to send bags up.